# npm install npm run build --prod / build is failed jenkins

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins

I'm building a project that uses react docker and Jenkins. last week the project is working fine and the build is success. unfortunately this week I got this error from Jenkins:

The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE.

actually, I'm new to react docker and Jenkins, so any suggestions would help. Thank you